# I would like to retrive JSON value and display it in wordpress page or widget

Tags: javascript, api, rest-api, json

i am looking for a solution in wordpress on how to retrieve only one value from exchange api json

json is avaible at: [LINK TO JSON](https://api.crex24.com/CryptoExchangeService/BotPublic/ReturnTicker?request=[NamePairs=BTC_BZK])

i would like to call value for Last variable in json and display it where code will be.

I tried several solutions, no luck for now

Thank you for your help!

Comment: yes i posted as answer :/

Answer (score 0):

I found some articles on net on how to proceed, tried this code:

$url = 'https://api.crex24.com/CryptoExchangeService/BotPublic/ReturnTicker?request=[NamePairs=BTC_BZK,BTC_DOGE]'; // path to your JSON file
$data = file_get_contents($url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
$characters = json_decode($data); // decode the JSON feed

echo $characters[0]->PairName;

foreach ($characters as $character) {
 echo $character->PairName . '
';
}